# Better approach for saving data for multiple tables using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I am currently using the following approach for saving my data in multiple tables in database, which I am extracting from excel files.

```
 public class Saver
{

   public static int SaveCensusBatch(string key, ICollection<tbl_Life_Census> collection)
   {
       using (var db = new AuraEntities())
       {
           var entry = new tbl_Life_Master() { UUID = key, tbl_Life_Census = collection };

           db.tbl_Life_Master.Add(entry);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return 1;
       }
   }

   public static int SaveLifeData(string key2, ICollection<tbl_Life_General_Info> collection)
   {
       using (var db = new AuraEntities())
       {
           var entry = new tbl_Life_Master() { UUID = key2, tbl_Life_General_Info = collection };

           db.tbl_Life_Master.Add(entry);

           db.SaveChanges();
           return 1;
       }
   }

   public static T GetDBRecordByPK<T>(string key) where T : class
   {
       using (var db = new AuraEntities())
       {
           var t = db.Set<T>().Find(key);
           return t;
       }
   }  

}
```

Following is the code for calling this in main:

```
foreach (var r in results)
                {
                    r.UUID = key.ToString();
                }


                Saver.SaveCensusBatch(key.ToString(), results);
                Saver.SaveLifeData(key.ToString(), results3);
                var master = Saver.GetDBRecordByPK<tbl_Life_Master>(key.ToString());
```

Please suggest me how can I do everything under one 'using block' and one function only instead of implementing several functions. This is because I have to insert data into 20-30 tables simultaneously.

Comment: Very unclear. What is `results` and where does it come form? Why do you set `r.UUID`? What is `results3` and where does it come from? Why do you have this `Saver` class in the first place? Why don't you save everything directly in the last code snippet?

Comment: Thanks I did the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by making all the Saver class' methods non-static (it also prevents keeping data in memory when you don't need it), and make it implement IDisposable interface. After that, you only need to follow the disposable pattern that Microsoft suggests (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
public class Saver : IDisposable
{
    private readonly AuraEntities db;
    private bool disposed;

    public Saver()
    {
        db = new AuraEntities();
        disposed = false;
    }

    public int SaveCensusBatch(string key, ICollection<tbl_Life_Census> collection)
    {
       var entry = new tbl_Life_Master() { UUID = key, tbl_Life_Census = collection };

       db.tbl_Life_Master.Add(entry);
       return 1;
   }

    public int SaveLifeData(string key2, ICollection<tbl_Life_General_Info> collection)
    {
       var entry = new tbl_Life_Master() { UUID = key2, tbl_Life_General_Info = collection };

       db.tbl_Life_Master.Add(entry);

       return 1;
    }

    public T GetDBRecordByPK<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        var t = db.Set<T>().Find(key);
        return t;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing && db != null)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then calling the methods within an using statement like this:

```
using(var saver = new Saver())
{
    saver.SaveCensusBatch(key.ToString(), results);
    saver.SaveLifeData(key.ToString(), results3);
    saver.Save();
}
```

Updated: It is better if you save from outside the saver class. Because he whole process will behave as a single transaction, and it won't be persisted if an exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You could select your results into a List and pass the list to the function. In that save function you could do your loop for each UUID and have the code for the three previous functions within the loop. Then call the db.SaveChanges() at the end outside the loop. The db.saveChanges() works as a transaction and would rollback if there was an error at any point during the save.

Comment: Can you do a snippet for me? because I was trying to that but I am having some problems with the syntax and all. I am new to entity framework. Please help if possible

Comment: can you just tell me how to put all results in a list as they are already in separate lists